# Improper or Undefined

Tags: real-analysis, definition, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)=0 $ if $x\neq 1   $    and  $f(1)=\infty $ then the Riemann integral

$\int_{0} ^1 f(x)$  $ dx $ = $ 0 $   or is it undefined?

If we take it as a legitimate function for improper  Riemann integral ,then as a limit this

seems to be true.Otherwise it is undefined.Do we allow infinite values for improper Riemann

integral?
                             Thanks in advance..

Comment: You may be interested in looking up Dirac measure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure

Comment: Usually, one accepts only real-valued functions for proper Riemann integrals, that is your $f$ is defined only on $[0,1)$.

Comment: @HalilDuru Consider my answer wrong, I didn't notice you were asking about the _Riemann_ integral, sorry

Comment: ok, no problem..

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integral over [a,b] is the same as the integral over (a,b) since the value of a single point (or a finite number of them) doesn't change the value of the integral. Here you can see an explanation: http://www.matematicasvisuales.com/english/html/analysis/piecewise/discontpieceslinear.html

Comment: The thing is that the area under a point on the plane has to be zero, since it has no width. The Riemann integral can be approximated by nested rectangles under the function (in fact it is the limit of this approximations), so the single value of a point, whose "rectangle's approximation" has width zero, doesn't change the total area.You can find information about these approximations by rectangle's thing all over the internet; wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral